# I'm receiving an error when formatting a date in Python, why?

Tags: python, datetime

This is my code for formatting a date:

```
def updateUserDBDates():
    global userDB, currentDate, previousDate, changeInDate

    index = 0
    index2 = 0

    userDB[1] = datetime.strptime("%d-%m-%Y", userDB[0])
    userDB[0] = datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

    saveData()

    currentDate = userDB[0]
    previousDate = userDB[1]
    changeInDate = currentDate - previousDate
```

and I get this error:

```
  File "/home/nathan/Documents/project001/programFiles/Project 001.py", line 170, in updateUserDBDates
    userDB[1] = datetime.strptime("%d-%m-%Y", userDB[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '%d-%m-%Y' does not match format '28-09-2013'
```

From what I can see everything should work fine, what is causing this error and how can I fix it easily?

Comment: The error is clear enough: ***time data** '%d-%m-%Y' does not match **format** '28-09-2013'*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) receive `date_str`, `format` as arguments (not `format`, `date_str`):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('28-09-2013', '%d-%m-%Y')
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 28, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument ordering for `strptime()` is wrong.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime